# Can't change anything in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.04

I've seen two different methods for making changes to GRUB:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and then run `sudo update-grub`
2. Install grub-customizer and use that to make changes.

None of these methods work for me. I've tried to change boot order, screen resolution, time period before default is selected, etc., but nothing works. When I reboot I get the exact same grub as always.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I should mention that my laptop is a dual-boot with Windows 10.

EDIT2: boot-repair output on https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BBqgM7NVZB/

Comment: Do you have more than one OS installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that - I have Windows 10 also.

Comment: What do you mean with `boot order`? Grub doesn't have a boot order, it has a default entry which will be booted after timeout automatically, that's all. In dualboot-configuration grub will refuse to set GRUB_TIMEOUT to zero.

Comment: Ah - sorry - bad wording. I tried to change the order of the different entries. I also tried to disable the timeout feature, so that the selection menu stays on-screen until a choice is made. But anything I change - resolution, too - is ignored.

Comment: I think we'd need to take a deeper look into your system to solve this issue. Would you mind to run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to create a boot-info summary and then add the link to the summary to your question? Don't run the recommended repair, just create the summary. This would answer hundrets of question we'd have to ask you.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the advice! I've added a link to the output to the post.

Comment: Grub Customizer overwrites grub script files with its versions. And if you reinstall grub you overwrite the Grub Customizer version. Report did not print /boot/grub/grub.cfg which it normally does print. you set grub default, but that description has to exactly match the menuentry in grub.cfg. And you used a very old vga setting. You should use GRUB_GFXMODE= and your correct size. Not sure if you can edit colors in /etc/default/grub. I use 40_custom, but this has another way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays#GRUB_2_Colors Incorrect entries in grub prevent update.